What does "You have requested a non-existent service "afform_scanner" mean during an upgrade?
During the upgrade to 5.72 from 5.69.5, Wordpress, I got the following error:
[Error: Finish core DB updates 5.72.0]]
However going to CiviCRM it appears like everything is fine - no issues on system status page. was my upgrade successful? Should i revert to previous version?

Edit: Reverted changes for now.
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: "You have requested a non-existent service "afform_scanner"."

#0 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(600): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition("afform_scanner")
#1 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(558): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet("afform_scanner", 1)
#2 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi.php(175): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get("afform_scanner")
#3 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/afform/core/Civi/Api4/Action/Afform/Get.php(20): Civi::service("afform_scanner")
#4 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/BasicGetAction.php(51): Civi\Api4\Action\Afform\Get->getRecords()
#5 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(70): Civi\Api4\Generic\BasicGetAction->_run(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))
#6 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(156): Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke(Object(Civi\Api4\Action\Afform\Get))
#7 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(256): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Action\Afform\Get))
#8 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/afform/core/afform.php(575): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
#9 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(276): afform_civicrm_referenceCounts(Object(CRM_Search_DAO_SearchDisplay), (Array:0))
#10 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/WordPress.php(136): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:43), "civicrm_referenceCounts", 2, Object(CRM_Search_DAO_SearchDisplay), (Array:0), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#11 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(314): CRM_Utils_Hook_WordPress->invokeViaUF(2, Object(CRM_Search_DAO_SearchDisplay), (Array:0), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_referenceCounts")
#12 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(251): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), "hook_civicrm_referenceCounts", Object(Civi\Core\UnoptimizedEventDispatcher))
#13 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(73): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners((Array:1), "hook_civicrm_referenceCounts", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#14 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(263): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), "hook_civicrm_referenceCounts")
#15 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(168): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_referenceCounts", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent))
#16 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(873): CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke((Array:2), Object(CRM_Search_DAO_SearchDisplay), (Array:0), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_referenceCounts")
#17 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(2672): CRM_Utils_Hook::referenceCounts(Object(CRM_Search_DAO_SearchDisplay), (Array:0))
#18 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Utils/CoreUtil.php(326): CRM_Core_DAO->getReferenceCounts()
#19 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(379): Civi\Api4\Utils\CoreUtil::getRefCount("SearchDisplay", 38)
#20 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(180): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->removeStaleEntity((Array:8))
#21 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(115): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEntities((Array:212))
#22 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(423): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcile()
#23 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(774): CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches(FALSE, FALSE)
#24 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php(101): CRM_Upgrade_Form::doCoreFinish(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), "5.72.alpha1", "5.72.0", "5.72.0", "/tmp/civicrm-post-upgradeMInpJS")
#25 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(255): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
#26 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(36): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(TRUE)
#27 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(93): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#28 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(38): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#29 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(291): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#30 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:17))
#31 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#32 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#33 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#34 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#35 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#36 /home/tarabnyc/www/www/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#37 {main}

CiviCRM status page says an upgrade is available but when I go to upgrade civicrm it says i am on latest version.


Yeah, the Upgrade has been completed and that error normally occurs when trying to rebuild the Cache.
Visit the extension page to check if there are pending patches
Visit the CiviCRM admin console to see if there are missing extensions needs to installed.
Ref: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4267

There is one extension I have not updated (extended report) because we are not ready to transition to Smarty V3 - will disable it during next attempt to see if that helps.

Did upgrade to 5.72.1 this time with smarty upgrade and all extensions updated - unfortunately same thing happened - but everything else seems to be fine.
